# c++ hdf5: how to design program for easy extension to new compound datatypes

Tags: c++, hdf5

The situation:
I am creating a class that serves as API to hdf5 in C++, basically encapsulating all the nitty-gritty details of the hdf5 C API.
I expect varying requirements in the future in terms of compound datatypes to be stored.
The compound datatypes will be C structs. I cannot simply use templates for storing different structs in the database since each struct requires its own function to set up the corresponding hdf5 compound datatype (offset of the elements etc), so this is not sufficient:

```
class simDB{
  public:
    template<class T> int write_to_dataset(vector<T> mydata){...}
}
```

Instead, I thought to create a separate header file for each upcoming datatype:

```
// type1_t.h
struct type1_t{
  int bla1;
  double bla2;
};

hid_t type1_memtype(){
  hid_t memtype = H5Tcreate(H5T_COMPOUND, sizeof(type1_t));
  herr_t status = H5Tinsert (memtype, "bla1", HOFFSET (type1_t, bla1), H5T_NATIVE_INT);
  herr_t status = H5Tinsert (memtype, "bla2", HOFFSET (type1_t, bla2), H5T_NATIVE_DOUBLE);
}
```

However, this does not get me much further since I still need to write a separate read/write function for each datatype, since for each type I need to call the correct memtype function. Turning the above code into a class does not seem to be feasible either since as far as I know the memory layout of a struct and a object is only guaranteed if the object has no methods - but I would need the member function shown above to produce the hdf5 datatype.

How can I structure the program in a way to minimize effort later on if I want to add new types of structs to save, i.e. new hdf5 compound datatypes?

Comment: something like boost::any comes to mind

Answer (score 2):

Would template specialization suit your needs?

```
template <> get_memtype<type1_t> {
    hid_t memtype = H5Tcreate(H5T_COMPOUND, sizeof(type1_t));
    herr_t status = H5Tinsert (memtype, "bla1", HOFFSET (type1_t, bla1), H5T_NATIVE_INT);
    herr_t status = H5Tinsert (memtype, "bla2", HOFFSET (type1_t, bla2), H5T_NATIVE_DOUBLE);
}
```

so later on you can get the datatype using `get_memtype<T>()`.

Comment: it did indeed! thanks a lot, while i was aware of the technique, i was not aware of it matching my problem :)